# Folders Completely Hidden Except via Save As

Tags: windows, directory-listing

I'm using an audio program called Supercollider on Windows 10. I have saved some files in a folder called "tunes" from SC via Save As, but Windows Explorer and CMD both seem unable to recognise access or recognise the "tunes" folder.

`C:\Users\HP>cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\SuperCollider-3.7.2\supercollider-robin\tunes"
The system cannot find the path specified.`

`C:\Program Files (x86)\SuperCollider-3.7.2\supercollider-robin>dir/a` doesn't show it either.

However, when saving from SC with Save As, it's there clear as day. I can even shift+right-click to get the path: `"C:\Program Files (x86)\SuperCollider-3.7.2\supercollider-robin\tunes"`

This makes no sense to me. Can anyone explain and tell me how to access my folder tunes folder please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This sounds like the UAC "Virtualization" file redirection feature. Since you normally don't have modify rights to the "Program Files" folders, Windows redirects all file writes to your own **`%LOCALAPPDATA%\VirtualStore`** folder instead. (This only happens with 32-bit programs.)

- Old New Thing: [I saved some files into the Program Files directory, and now they’re gone!](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20150902-00/?p=91681)

You can usually just drag the files out of the "Save As" box onto your desktop, or open the above path to VirtualStore via Explorer or CMD.

Comment: Excellent. Thank you. Unfortunately I get an error with dragging, but the main thing is I can now access my work outside of the SC IDE.